# How to copy, scrape or export dropdown options?

Tags: html, jquery

Sometimes I need to copy the data of a dropdown I find on a website.

How can I copy and export the options data with jQuery?

Comment: this is not a blog or a wiki.  The self-answering option is to provide a solution if you found a solution meanwhile or with the help of others. It is not to post questions and then self answering it in the same instance to farm reputation.

Comment: I don't get why wouldn't I do this, because as far as I know Stackoverflow also works as a wiki. I'm not necessarily trying to get reputation, that would be a side effect. I just figured out more people (including myself) would look for this solution at some point in time. I think it is a normal behavior to post question+answer as a wiki if you think you can help more users. Isn't it?

Answer (score -2):

For example with Chrome you can:

Inspect the dropdown element.

[image: Inspect dropdown with Chrome]

Then run this code in the console tab:

```
var data=[];    
$('#cuenta-tipo option').each(function() {
    data.push({
        id: $(this).val(),
        value: $(this).text()
    });
    
});
console.log(data);
```

Change code to match the dropdown selector you're interested in, for this example there is a select with id `#cuenta-tipo`.

Also we're using jQuery here, but if the website you're interested doesn't have jQuery you can just convert the code to vanilla JS.

Then last step, right click on the object printed in the console, and copy the object:

[image: Chrome Console copy json object]

Finally, you end up with this "beautiful" data in JSON:

```
[
    {
        "id": "",
        "value": "Tipo cuenta"
    },
    {
        "id": "1000",
        "value": "100 Capital social"
    },
    {
        "id": "1010",
        "value": "101 Fondo social"
    },
    // ...
]
```

And if you need to further process that data, for example from PHP, you can decode the JSON and loop the array and do whatever you need to do with it:

```
<?php
$json=<<<EOF
[
    {
        "id": "",
        "value": "Tipo cuenta"
    },
    {
        "id": "1000",
        "value": "100 Capital social"
    },
    {
        "id": "1010",
        "value": "101 Fondo social"
    }
]
EOF;

$rows= json_decode($json, true);
```